# Could not load file or assembly for external dll

Tags: c#, com, minitab

I am trying to create a **Minitab Add in** using **COM** in C#. I am adding some external reference such as **ZedGraph** or **OxyPlot**. But every time it is unable to find dll.
[image]

If I use dll as embedded resource, then it throws:

**external component has thrown an exception**

I have tried putting dlls together but still no luck. It would be great if someone help me sort out.

Comment: Can you provide some code; a github repo should be ideal :)

Comment: @Hackerman Sure, here is the link. https://github.com/waqar-ahmed/TechmaxMinitabAddIn . Im calling the ZedGraph library in BAPlot.cs And AddIn.cs is the file which is initially called by the Minitab, when it loads the dll.

Comment: This is a standard mishap when creating a [ComVisible] assembly, the CLR look for dependent assemblies in the normal places.  So not the directory where you put your assembly, it looks in the directory where the EXE is stored and in the GAC.  Using ILMerge is a standard workaround, but you should do this only after you've debugged your code and figured out the reason for the exception.  So just copy the dependent assemblies in the EXE directory until you get there.

Comment: @HansPassant Im getting external component has thrown an exception now.

Comment: Congratulations, good luck debugging it.

Comment: Can you please give any hint how I can debug it? because that dll is being loaded via com in Minitab.